# Why do I see a Desktop device in Apple iTunes Connect devices?

Tags: ios, itunes-store

We have an iOS app (only) - no Desktop version. When I go to "Sales & Trends" then drill down into the Application -> Devices I see "Desktop" has a huge number of "Units". What does that mean given there is no Desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a Desktop version: the iOS version. Thanks to the new generation of Apple Silicon machines, *any* iOS app can run on the desktop. So those are all M1 users trying out your app on the desktop.

Comment: One would have to have spent the last year vacationing on Mars not to be aware of this! :) Indeed, Apple warned you very clearly that this would happen, and that if you didn't want it to, you would need to opt out explicitly.